# PostgreSQL column to keep track of number of appearances of a certain kind

Tags: postgresql, database-sequence

I have to make a new column inside of an already existing database that keeps track of the number of occurences of a certain kind. Here's an example to be more clear:

```
id | eqid | etcd | this would be my new column
-------------------------
1  | 4   | abc  | 1
2  | 3   | def  | 1
3  | 1   | ghi  | 1
4  | 4   | jkl  | 2
5  | 3   | mno  | 2
6  | 4   | pqr  | 3
```

I am trying to make this column to be able to get all the EQID's of a certain value and get their position. For example: in the example above, let's say you want to get the first EQID that is equal to 4 and that has it's ETCD equal to "abc" in this example to become the second EQID equal to 4 thanks to a button and the second EQID to become the first, I would increment the one with the ETCD equal to "abc" and decrement the one with the ETCD equal to "jkl".
I have tried finding answers everywhere but I haven't found an answer that could help me out. Thanks for any help. By the way this column must be saved it can not be a temporary column or anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Window function Row_Number(). See [demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=ef47bf9c0108dff6f4270c5fed3e6b64)

```
select id, eqid ,etcd 
     ,  row_number() over( partition by  eqid order by id) "This is new column"      
   from sample_data
   order by id;
```

You should look into and become familiar with [Window Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/tutorial-window.html) and the documentation references there.